# Select that returns only new status changes

Tags: sql, select, subquery, relational-database, where-clause

I would like to select all the accounts that status changed to B1 during the month of December 2020. That is, the accounts that now have B1 status and in the previous record did not have.
Records with VALID_TO_DATE = 31/12/2100 (DD/MM/YYYY) are the most recent records.

However, there are cases, such as account 400, that the change in status occurred in the penultimate record, which is no longer valid. But as the change happened in December and the status is the same as the valid record, my select statement must include account 400.

**Desired result:** In this sense, according to the data below, I need a select that returns only accont **100 and 400**

| ROW | ACCOUNT_ID | ACCOUNT_CHANGE_DATE | VALID_TO_DATE | ACCOUNT_STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 21/10/2020 | 05/12/2020 | A1 |
| 2 | 100 | 05/12/2020 | 15/12/2020 | A1 |
| 3 | 100 | 15/12/2020 | 31/12/2100 | B1 |
| 4 | 200 | 09/11/2020 | 22/12/2020 | A1 |
| 5 | 200 | 22/12/2020 | 25/12/2020 | A1 |
| 6 | 200 | 25/12/2020 | 31/12/2100 | A1 |
| 7 | 300 | 11/11/2020 | 19/11/2020 | B1 |
| 8 | 300 | 19/11/2020 | 23/12/2020 | A1 |
| 9 | 300 | 23/12/2020 | 31/12/2100 | A1 |
| 10 | 400 | 16/11/2020 | 14/12/2020 | A1 |
| 11 | 400 | 14/12/2020 | 18/12/2020 | B1 |
| 12 | 400 | 18/12/2020 | 31/12/2100 | B1 |

My source table has records of all changes that affected each of the accounts, which may or may not change the status of the respective account.

This is my incomplete/wrong attempt:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID
FROM TABLE t1
where ACCOUNT_STATUS ="B1"
      AND ACCOUNT_CHANGE_DATE BETWEEN '01/12/2020' AND '31/12/2020' 
      AND VALID_TO_DATE = '31/12/2100'
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE t2
                      WHERE t2.ACCOUNT_ID = t1.ACCOUNT_ID 
                            AND t2.ACCOUNT_STATUS = 'B1' 
                            AND t2.ACCOUNT_CHANGE_DATE < t1.ACCOUNT_CHANGE_DATE);
```

Comment: Which database?  MySQL 5.x?  MySQL 8?  Oracle 18c?  SQL Server 2019? etc, etc

Comment: What if the first record in December is B1, but it finished as A1 in November?  Also, are your date columns strings or some kind of date/time/timestamp data type?  *(I strongly suggest using ISO data formats for literal date values, such as `'2020-12-01'`)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to select all the accounts that status changed to B1 during the month of December 2020.

Use `lag()`:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             lag(status) over (partition by account_id order by ACCOUNT_CHANGE_DATE) as prev_status
      from t1
     ) t1
where prev_status <> 'B1' and status = 'B1' and
      account_change_date >= '2021-12-01' and
      account_change_date < '2022-01-01'
```